# How can I improve the performance when using TABLE_PER_CLASS that causes several lot of tables in a queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a tree structure defined in hibernate. Where I have an abstract element called TreeObject. A tree object can have several children and only one parent.

I also have some implementation for this class: form, category, group of questions and question. All of them inherits from TreeObject.

The idea is that a form can have as children categories and questions. The category can have as children groups and questions, and groups can have as children other groups and questions.

Then I have defined the TreeObject as:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TreeObject{

    @ManyToOne
    private TreeObject parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<TreeObject> children;

    [...]
}
```

Then, the other objects are very simple. For example, the form element is:

```
@Entity
public class Form extends TreeObject {
    [...]
}
```

And the other elements are similar, except by some irrelevant code for this question.

The problem resides when I want to retrieve the children of an element (as TreeObject is not a real table in the database). For example, to get all children of a form, hibernates create multiples union from the tables `Form`, `Category`, `Group`, `Question` for representing the `TreeObject` table equivalence and selecting the children. When the database has several elements (but not so much), getting the children can takes around 0.5secs due to the multiple union generated. Then when I will have a big amount of data, I am going to have big performance issues with that query.

For example, an example of a query obtained to get a form is:

```
select form0_.ID as ID1_7_0_, form0_.createdBy as createdB3_7_0_,  form0_.name as name2_12_0_, form0_.parent_ID as parent_I5_12_0_, children1_.parent_ID as parent_I5_7_1_, children1_.ID as ID1_12_1_, children1_.ID as ID1_7_2_, children1_.createdBy as createdB3_7_2_, children1_.name as name2_12_2_, children1_.parent_ID as parent_I5_12_2_, children1_.version as version2_2_2_, children1_.clazz_ as clazz_2_, questionva2_.BaseQuestionWithValue_ID as BaseQues1_7_3_, questionva2_.questionValues as question2_38_3_, treeobject3_.ID as ID1_7_4_, treeobject3_.comparationId as comparat2_7_4_, treeobject3_.name as name2_12_4_, treeobject3_.parent_ID as parent_I5_12_4_, treeobject3_.clazz_ as clazz_4_ from form form0_ left outer join 
( select ID, name, parent_ID, 10 as clazz_ from questions
    union select ID, name, parent_ID, 24 as clazz_ from group 
    union select ID, name, parent_ID, 32 as clazz_ from category 
    union select ID, name, parent_ID, 26 as clazz_ from form ) 
children1_ on form0_.ID=children1_.parent_ID left outer join 
    question_with_values questionva2_ on children1_.ID=questionva2_.BaseQuestionWithValue_ID left outer join 
        ( select ID, name, parent_ID, 10 as clazz_ from questions
        union select ID, name, parent_ID, 24 as clazz_ from group 
        union select ID, name, originalReference, parent_ID, 32 as clazz_ fromcategory 
        union select ID, comparationId, name, parent_ID, 26 as clazz_ from form ) 
    treeobject3_ on form0_.parent_ID=treeobject3_.ID where form0_.ID=344820 order by children1_.sortSeq asc;
```

(note: I have removed several columns to make it simpler to understand the code)

Now I have use `@BatchSize` to increase performance, and the general performance of the application is better, but still is not a real solution.

My idea is to use something like `@WhereJoinTable` to filter the 'big' union query and only retrieve the real children from Category and Questions and not all of them, avoiding the performance issue. But as children parameter is mappedBy by `parent`, I have not any clue how can I achieve this.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_ID")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause=" ???? ")
    private TreeObject parent;
```

Maybe with `@Filter` option of Hibernate:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_ID")
    @Filter(name="parentGroup",condition=" ???? ") 
    private TreeObject parent;
```

Of course, another solution is to change the `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` to only have one big table and therefore the `union` will not appear in the query. But the database will be very hard to read, and I want to avoid it.

The question is: exists any way to improve the Hibernate performance for retrieve all children of a TreeObject?

Comment: Could you post SQL generated?

Comment: Yes sure. I have edited the SQL to make it a little sorted removing some columns that are useless for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ManyToOne` annotation is by default `EAGER` and I think you don't really need the parent of the objects you are loading directly (via primary key), right?

You could change the association like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private TreeObject parent;
```

This should at least remove the last join with the unions.

But due to the nature of your model (it's a recursion) you will never be able to select an entire object graph without a native query, because JPA simply doesn't support it. Even a native query may not be the best solution and I think you should consider using a document store which enables you to store/load entire graphs in one operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "using a document store"?

Comment: @JorgeHortelano Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database#Implementations in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Still I would prefer to work with my current MySQL database until all possibilities are discarded. If `@Where` or `@Filter` don't help as you suggested, then I need to find a different approach. But I want to go deeper into my JPA/hibernate knowledge and I want to see if there is any better solution. Of course, a different solution would be to export the `Form` entitiy to JSON and store it into MySQL as pure text, that will avoid all my issues. But it does not teach me anything new about Hibernate.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano If it is JPA/Hibernate you want to learn, you are right, a document store won't help. Did you try the `FetchType.LAZY` as I mentioned? As I said, it should reduce the complexity of your particular SQL statement by ~50%.

Comment: I really like your answer because I am focused in `@Where` but with only the `FetchType.LAZY` tag performance is improved around 20% in the application. That is a big improvement with a small change. I am afraid that this is the only improvement possible to the query as you suggested, or maybe also the joins can be reduced in size too by a different 'tune up'.